# заставлять входящие запросы ждать и возвращать результат первого запроса

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route("/get_data")
def get_data():
    result_data = #data extraction code
    return result_data
```

**Информация**:

Тут ипользуется Flask. Извлечение данных занимает 2 минуты.

**Ситуация**:

Получен запрос *"/get_data"* из одного ресурса, код запустился, данные начали извлекаться. Через 10 секунд, поступил второй запрос *"/get_data"* из другого ресурса. Через 15 секунд, постул еще один запрос *"/get_data"* из третьего ресурса.

**Необходимо**:

Необходимо, чтобы первый и второй запрос **ждали результата первого запроса**, и **вернули именно то, что вернул первый запрос**.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: А теперь все то же самое, только на Русском! ) Это SO на Русском языке.

Comment: точно, сейчас исправлю. спасибо

Comment: Поместите результат метода в кэш, по запросу из других ресурсов выдавайте сразу данные из кэша. Периодически проверяйте, изменились ли полученные данные с данными в кэше и обновите его, если требуется.

Comment: `Flask` насколько я помню вообще однопоточный, последующие запросы не будут обрабатываться, пока первый не закончится. Это нужно что-то более продвинутое использовать.